# How can I host my java server on a Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, server, vps

I have tomcat installed on vps, everything has been configured, but how do I host my java server on it? What extension should I use and which folder should I put? Or do I need to change something in the Server.java?

Here he is:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] ar) throws IOException {
        int port = 8080;
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");

            Socket socket = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("Got a client!");
            System.out.println();
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            String line = null;
            while(true) {
                line = in.readUTF(); 
                System.out.println("The dumb client just sent me this line : " + line);
                System.out.println("I'm sending it back...");
                out.writeUTF(line);
                out.flush();
                System.out.println("Waiting for the next line...");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch(Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont host your "java server" on tomcat. tomcat is already a java web server. it handles connections

Comment: Tomcat is unnecessary, just FTP your java code in your VPS and run it using the terminal.